# TDBGrid status bar for column aggregate

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, tdbgrid

Got a grid with some numeric columns and it's need to implement for each column an aggregate (sum or count) and display it under the corresponding column.

I know that some suites (DevExpress or other) had already implemented "by default". But there is a way to implement that using default controls or JVCL?

Comment: When you mentioned JVCL, there is the `TJvDBGridFooter`, what might actually be what you are looking for. It has the `OnCalculate` event published, however I don't know how about resizing of this control. Are you looking for a control that will be resized along with the grid columns ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have mentioned [`JEDI VCL`](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/), try to take a look at the [`TJvDBGridFooter`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvDBGridFooter) component. It is the status bar for the [`TJvDBGrid`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvDBGrid) control.

- you can modify the displayed text in the [`OnDisplayText`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvDBGridFooter.OnDisplayText) event
- you can calculate the aggregate fields in the [`OnCalculate`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvDBGridFooter.OnCalculate) event
- you can follow the grid column scroll, resize or modify the appearence of the panels

Check the demo projects from JVCL's `..\examples\JvUltimDBGrid` folder to see it in action.

Comment: Could You tell me - how to perform an agregate sum for an field and display it into footer. That example does not fullfill my needs - I use an ClientDataset.

Comment: So, did you found the way ? Basically, it's about [`aggregate fields`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29272) in a dataset. Then you add columns in the `TJvDBGridFooter.Columns` collection, set them `FieldName` to those aggregate fields from the connected dataset, set the `DisplayMask` like `Σ %d` and in `TJvDBGridFooter.OnCalculate` event fill the `CalcValue` parameter with the value from the aggregate field.